# Windows audio on speaker connect to remote computer

Tags: audio, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to have audio of windows server always running no matter
   I access this server by remote from other system.
   For example I have speakers connected to windows server, playing songs.
   Then after sometime, I took a remote of this server, and the sound is AWOL.
   I need this sound on the speakers connected to this server, not on the system that has remote access of this server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Remote Desktop [**RDC**] connection and select **Options** > **Local Resources**. **Configure Remote Computer Sound for** **Leave at remote computer**.

The Wording may be a little Different. This Would also depend if you were using RDC on Windows you didn't specify.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use RDP, if not, use VNC?

If using RDP then try using `mstsc.exe /admin` as this has had some success for others.

Although this is for 2008, it pretty much shares your experience, that it isn't possible via RDP http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/115028-rdp-disables-remote-sound/